# Calculate Probability from Moment Generating Function

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

Let  and  be two discrete random variables with the joint moment generating function

$$_{,}(t_{1},t_{2})=(\frac{1}{3} e^{t_{1}} + \frac{2}{3})^{2}  (\frac{2}{3} e^{t_{2}} + \frac{1}{3})^{3} ,t_{1},t_{2} \in R.$$
Then $P$ $( 2 + 3 > 1)$ equals

My Approch:

$ _{} = _{,}(t_{1},0) = (\frac{1}{3} e^{t_{1}} + \frac{2}{3})^{2} $
similar to MGF of $Binomial(2,\frac{1}{3})$

$ _{Y} = _{,}(0,t_{2}) = (\frac{2}{3} e^{t_{2}} + \frac{1}{3})^{3} $
similar to MGF of $Binomial(3,\frac{2}{3})$

$P$ $( 2 + 3 > 1) = 1 - P(X=0) P(Y=0) = 1 - (\frac{2}{3})^{2}(\frac{1}{3})^{3} \simeq  0.98 $

Is this a right approach to solve for this kind type of question?

What if in case, I don't know the MGF of known distribution?

Is there any general way to solve this kind of problems?

Comment: Why is $n=2$ at $Y$? At the mgf of $Y$ the exponent is $2$, a typo?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Corrected the same.

Comment: Since the joint MGF factors as the product of a function of $t_1$ and a function of $t_2$, each of which is an MGF, your random variables are independent.

Comment: The rest looks correct to me. I cannot think of a better approach.